# Publishing Android App from Visual Studio

Tags: android, zipalign

I do the following steps:

1. Click on Build (from VS)
2. Click on Archive (from the VS Dropdown)
   VS Archives the app as an APK (it's one file)
3. Click on Distribute
4. The Google Play Option is greyed out so I choose Ad Hoc
5. Add the Signing Identity
6. Open the Distribution folder
7. Run zipalign -p -f -v 4 on the apk specifying the output apk
8. Zipalign appears successful. So I try to upload to Google Play

9 UH OH:
You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature (learn more about signing). Error from apksigner: ERROR (Jar signer XXX.RSA): JAR signature META-INF/XXX.SF indicates the APK is signed using APK Signature Scheme v2 but no such signature was found. Signature stripped? ERROR (Jar signer XXX.RSA): JAR signature META-INF/XXX.SF indicates the APK is signed using APK Signature Scheme v3 but no such signature was found. Signature stripped?

OY VEY. What now?

Comment: What happens if you use Android Studio and do the same thing? Are you able to build a signed APK?

Comment: Don't know. Do not use Android Studio.

Comment: I can build the apk and I can distribute it, just not from Google play which is (to my thinking) critical.

Comment: If you sign and zipalign you have to align before signing or the signature is invalidated by aligning "If  you use apksigner, zipalign must only be performed before the APK file has been signed. If you sign your APK using apksigner and make further changes to the  APK,  its signature is invalidated.". I don't know what VSCode does, I wouldn't use it for android development but it most likely also zipaligns during the build/signing process

Comment: I don't see how I can do that. There doesn't seem to be a way to "interrupt" the process and insert zipalign and then sign the apk.